# cannot find my apps in the windows store

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have had some educational apps in the windows store for over 1 year. I cannot find now them when I search on app name or app keyword (such as algebra) or my own name. Strangely a few sold about a month ago, I don't know how that happened. I am using windows 10. Could that be a factor (is there a windows 10 store as distinct from the old one?) Thanks

Comment: This could be due to a change in the search logic in the Windows App store. I've noticed that most of the time, you'll need to search for the exact full name of the application to find it.